# Can anyone trace where I downloaded my copy of Tails?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails

I may be a bit paranoid, but can a hacker or anyone trace where I downloaded or where i copied the tails iso onto a usb while im using it? Can they track me somehow through the BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on what hackers can and can not do.

When you download Tails straight from their web site or the torrent to your home, without Tor or VPN, then your ISP can know (even with ssl, they can guess from the size) and Tails' hosting provider and webmaster can know. If you use the torrent, then pretty much everyone can know that you downloaded it.

Assuming that your computer is clean in the first place, downloading Tails does not introduce any new risk.

Once you have Tails downloaded, verified, and booted, there is no way to tell how or where you got it.

Comment: per the xkeyscore flags, downloading TAILS most certainly does introduce a risk: http://daserste.ndr.de/panorama/xkeyscorerules100.txt

Comment: Thanks for replying. So just to be clear, if i download Tails through Tor, and make the iso bootable on a usb, there is no way to tell what computer, IP, etc I got it from and what computer I created the bootable USB from? Is any kind of this info stored on the bootable usb? Just asking again, because like when you check properties on a file like a pdf or excel file, it shows who created it. Does it do anything like this? Thank you again.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.